# Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_Block_Parser_Block, because the name is already in use

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

currently changing the hosting and upload the back up, since then the wordpress dashboard not longer able to access and shows error:

Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_Block_Parser_Block, because the name is already in use /home/domains/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-block-parser.php on line 15

There has been a critical error on this website.

I don't have coding experience, how can I fix this problem?

Thank you you all in advance.

Access to Wordpress dashboard again but not changing the site content.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing the PHP version to a lower version. Say you're currently using PHP Version 8.2, try changing it to 8.1.

You can change the PHP version in 2 ways:

1. Login to your **cPanel** (https://**ChangeThisToYourDomainName**/cpanel > look for **MultiPHP Manager** or you can use the Search Tool
2. Using .htaccess file
   Locate the file in /home/domains/public_html/ > .htaccess > **right-click** on it, and select **edit file** and insert the PHP handler I provided below at the top of the your htaccess file:

```css
php – BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not editSet the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.<IfModule mime_module>AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml</IfModule>php – END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

**Note:* you can change this **“ea-php81”** to your preferred PHP version. For example, you'd like to use PHP version 80 then change it to **“ea-php80”***

Do not for to **save** the changes then load your site.

If this did not resolve the issue, I would recommend updating the WordPress core files specifically the **wp-includes**

1. You can do this by downloading the updated WordPress version https://wordpress.org/download/
2. Go to your File Manager > look for the foldeer mohsinbrother.com > upload the WordPress zip file > extract the zip filee and the path directory should be ***/home/domains/public_html/wordpress***
3. A folder name WordPress will show > look for **wp-includes** folder > right-click then select **move** > path should be ***/public_html***
4. Once done, check the site.

Note: Updating the core files will not override your web content as long as you only update the **wp-includes**